# Bitbucket Pipeline is supported in AWS china region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bitbucket-pipelines

I am planning to make use of Bitbucket pipeline for China AWS (lambda, Beanstalk) deployments. Is this possible?

Is there any technical difficulty for this - in terms of connectivity? We have HTTP/HTTPS port open with ICP procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Pipelines is currently running in a US AWS region. I'm not sure what restrictions you might have deploying to AWS China.

Perhaps you can set up an EC2 instance to SSH into and verify connectivity behaves as necessary.